# How to detect non-contiguous symbols using CV2?

Tags: python, ocr, opencv, text-recognition

I have a grayscale image of printed text. I want to extract every individual character from the image so that I can save them as discrete images. I don't want to *recognise* what the character is, I just want each glyph as a separate file.

I'm using `cv2`, for example:

```py
# Find contours to isolate individual letters
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`
```

That works perfectly for contiguous characters - that is, where the shape of the glyph has no breaks.

But it doesn't work on characters like `i`, `j`, `:`, and `;` - the dots on top are not included.

Is there a way to use CV2 to detect these characters? I know the document uses only Latin letters, numbers, and punctuation.

The document uses a fairly archaic typeface and doesn't work well with Tesseract or other traditional OCR engines - which is why I want to *detect* the individual letters, rather than try to *recognise* them.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz that's helpful. Given that I want to extract individual characters as images, which OCR engine would you recommend that I use?

Comment: Thanks again @ChristophRackwitz when you say "train a simple classifier" could you point me to some resources you personally recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [OpenCV's Erode / Dilate function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) to erode the image vertically.

```
kernel = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)

erode = cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations = 6)
```

That transformed this:

[image: Old printed text]

Into this:

[image: Text which has been vertically deformed]

That joined the dots on the `i` and `?` characters while leaving enough horizontal space to make detection possible.

I did the detection on the eroded image, but applied the cropping to the original image.